# vuex filter method not working corectly. It shows all items

Tags: javascript, filter, vuex, action, mutation

```
I have component Filter to find a title of movie from AllMovies.
When i filter, the movie list is not working properly
```

setFindMovies is method, filteredMovies is computed. It filter good, but when input in empty only shows firs element from regular array, not all array with elements

```
<FindMovie   @find-movie="setFindMovies" ></FindMovie>
 <TheMovie v-for="movie in filteredMovies" :key='movie.id' :id='movie.id' :title='movie.title' :year='movie.year' :description='movie.description'/>

setFindMovies(searchMovie){
    this.activeMovies=searchMovie
    console.log(searchMovie)
  },

            filteredMovies(){
              let movies=  this.$store.getters['movies/movies'];   
      let copyMovies=[]    
        if (this.activeMovies.title) {
          console.log(this.activeMovies.title)
             movies=movies.filter(movie=>{
            let matchTitle=movie.title.includes(this.activeMovies.title)
            if(matchTitle){
                copyMovies.push({
                title:movie.title,
                year:movie.year,
                description:movie.description,
                id:movie.id
              })
              return movies=copyMovies
            }
            } 
          )
        }
          return movies
```

Comment: You haven't added the code for the movie list. Please edit your question and add the same so that other can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey @Amit, I  change it, but still not working good